# How To Know Error Response in DotNet using database SQL Server?

Tags: .net

I'm new on DotNet Framework (i'm using code igniter before), I try to post data into my SQL Server. 
This is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public Response Post([FromBody] Log_Ups_User log_user)
    {
        Response response = new Response();
        try
        {
            LogAccessLayer log = new LogAccessLayer();
            log.AddUpsUser(log_user);                
            response.data = null;
            response.message = "Inserted";
            response.status = "Ok";

        }
        catch
        {

            response.data = null;
            response.message = "Error";
            response.status = "Sial";
        }
        return response;
    }
```

then my Response.cs

```
public class Response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

I post the data using Postman and it return

> "status": "Sial",
>       "data": null,
>       "message": "Error"

But I don't know which part or which line of my code that cause error.
How to return error that can give me some information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Exceptional block into your code. From your example try to modify your code just likes this. So you can see error message..

```
 public Response Post([FromBody] Log_Ups_User log_user)
{
    Response response = new Response();
    try
    {
        LogAccessLayer log = new LogAccessLayer();
        log.AddUpsUser(log_user);                
        response.data = null;
        response.message = "Inserted";
        response.status = "Ok";

    }
    catch(Exceptional ex)
    {

        response.data = null;
        response.message = ex.ToString();
        response.status = "Sial";
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's great. Read below link & try to use exceptional block inside every methods of your project.
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-exception-handling